# How to randomly select on a column in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table in redshift that has a column called ID with millions of distinct entries. However, each ID can be repeated across rows. An example of my table would be:

| ID | Color | Age | Height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Blue | 12 | 24 |
| A | Red | 3 | 34 |
| B | Green. | 6 | 26 |
| B | Blue | 8 | 22 |
| C | White | 6 | 34 |

I want to select a preset amount - say 100,000 distinct IDs, and all the rows that match onto those IDs. So if ID 'A' were randomly selected, I'd get back all the rows (2) that have 'A' in the ID.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: If an ID is not unique is it truly an ID? Sounds more like a foreign key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `join` and select the appropriate ids in a subquery:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select id
      from t
      group by id
      order by random()
      limit 1000000
     ) t1000000
     on t1000000.id = t.id;
```

You might find it faster to avoid the sort.  For instance, if you want a 1% sample of the ids, instead:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select id
      from t
      group by id
      having random() < 0.01
     ) t1000000
     on t1000000.id = t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know redshift so pardon my ignorance but could you do a sub-select like:

```
    SELECT TOP 1
           ID
          ,CAST(RANDOM() * 100 As int) As rand_int
    FROM tbl_name
    ORDER BY rand_int
```

Using that, INNER JOIN your main table based upon the ID column?